# ngImgCrop is not working through modal popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im using img-crop directive,when I am placing this directive in modal popup content its not working and not showing image and crop area.Im using material design md-dialog as popup..Here is my sample code..

```
<div class="cropArea">

    <img-crop image="myImage" area-type={{areaType}} result-image="myCroppedImage">
    </img-crop>
</div>
```

and this is my modal popup:

```
 $scope.showImage = function (ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                templateUrl: '/demo/modelPopup.html',
                targetEvent: ev
            }).then();
        };
```

not exactly this,but I want to do cropping in popup instead of my page...Plz help me.....

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my answer on [ngImgCrop not working inside UI Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540382/ngimgcrop-not-working-inside-ui-modal). The basic problem is that you are trying to bind an event on a DOM element that might not exist at the time you do the binding. The work around is to wrap the binding in a timeout as shown in the linked answer.