# ngImgCrop not working inside UI Modal

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using the ngImgCrop angular directive to resize and crop an image. However when I try and use it inside a UI Modal controller it doesn't work.

The issue I believe is that the below line does not get properly set because the DOM is not created. The handlefileselect function never gets called?!

Does anybody know how to properly use this directive inside a Modal or how to make this work?

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect);
```

The modal contoller code is here

```
.controller('ProfilePictureModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items,$timeout) {

    $scope.myImage = '';
    $scope.myCroppedImage = '';

    var handleFileSelect = function (evt) {

        alert("Here");

        var file = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            $scope.$apply(function ($scope) {
                $scope.myImage = evt.target.result;
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }


    angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect);

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.optionItems);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is spot on. I had a similar issue and the problem is with that line:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect);
```

The problem here is you are trying to bind an event on a DOM element that might not exist at the time you do the binding. I found a work around that others were using (more info [here](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop/issues/41)). The work around is to wrap the binding in a timeout like below:

```
$timeout(function() {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect);
},1000, false);
```

The above will try to do the binding a second later after the modal controller code executes. You can increase the delay if necessary.